# Where are the jquery ui files?

Tags: jquery-ui, npm, nuget

Project: .Net Core 2.1, MVC. Tried installing jquery ui via nuget. Package installs but no files appear in solution explorer. Tried `npm install jquery-ui-dist`. Package appears in NPM in the solution explorer but no files appear anywhere.

Where are the files?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The files are there but hidden...

I have no idea *why* it's hidden but it is.

[image: The files are there but hidden...]